# ng-init doesn't work in ionic collection-repeat block

Tags: angularjs, collections, ionic-framework, repeat, angularjs-ng-init

I'm using the following view:

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="scan in scans" href="#/app/scans/{{scan.local_id}}">
  <h2 class="media-heading">ID: {{(scan.id ? scan.id : '--')}}</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div><b>Status</b></div>
      <div><b>Photos</b></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div>{{getStatus(scan.status)}}</div>
      <div><span ng-init="setNumberOfPhotos(scan)" ng-bind="numberOfPhotos[scan.local_id]"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

Everything is working fine, the controller function `setNumberOfPhotos(scan)` called with `undefined` value, and I see the error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'local_id' of undefined
    at Scope.setNumberOfPhotos (file:///android_asset/www/components/scans/scan.list.controller.js:83:35)
```

The error appears many time, so at every loop, but it seems that `ng-init` doesn't evaulated at every loop. Any idea?

Comment: Can you show us a demo object of your array `scans`?

Comment: It has no meaning, what is in `scans`. **Undefined** value is passed to the function `setNumberOfPhotos` in `ng-init`. But anyway `scans` is an array of hash objects with a couple fields. In the example  `scan.id`, `scan.local_id` (as href) appear correctly.